# MYSQL Join: find all matches from table a , even if not present in table b

Tags: mysql

i have a table a:

```
id  | name | ...
1     paul
2     paula
```

and a table b

```
id | nameId | active
1    1        1
```

And try to come up with a query that would result in the following:

```
id  | name | active
1     paul   1
2     paula
```

Nevermind the fact that the example data does not make much sense please.

My problem is that i need a query that selects all records from table a that match some condition, and finds a certain value for those results in table B, if present, and adds it to the result set, but without omitting those results from table a that have no match in table b.

so far i have tried something like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.active FROM a left join b b.nameId=a.id WHERE (something)
```

But that gives me only the first row.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do show the WHERE condition also. It must not have anything relating to b with a specific value.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is the correct way to go here.  The only explanation I can think of for this is that your `WHERE` clause is filtering off records, or the query you actually ran is not what you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should give the desired result, at least minus the mystery `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.name,
       COALESCE(CAST(b.active AS CHAR(50)), 'NA')   -- replace NULL with NA
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
    ON a.id = b.nameId
-- WHERE (you can add a WHERE clause, but it might filter off rows)
```

Comment: You are right, the problem is in my WHERE clause... thank you for pointing me in the right direction. This also means my question does not reflect my actual problem, so unless i get things working i will write a new one. Thank you for your help!